# Issues bruteforcing password with python

Tags: python

I am working on some code for an assignment that it's supposed to brute-force a zip file. I was provided the first word of the password and I know that it has 3 more alphabet characters including uppercase and lowercase.

I am able to print each one of those combinations, but it seems to not find the password. Can somebody take a look at my code and see if you find a bug or something?

```py
import zipfile
import itertools
import time

# Function for extracting zip files to test if the password works!
def extractFile(zip_file, password):
    try:
        zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)
        return True
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
    except Exception:
        pass

# Main code starts here...
# The file name of the zip file.
zipfilename = 'planz.zip'
# The first part of the password. We know this for sure!
first_half_password = 'Super'
# We don't know what characters they add afterwards...
# This is case sensitive!
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename)

# We know they always have 3 characters after Super...
# For every possible combination of 3 letters from alphabet...
for c in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=3):
    # Slowing it down on purpose to make it work better with the web terminal
    # Remove at your peril
    time.sleep(0.009)
    # Add the three letters to the first half of the password.
    password = first_half_password+''.join(c)
    # Try to extract the file.
    print ("Trying: %s" % password)
    # If the file was extracted, you found the right password.
    if extractFile(zip_file, password):
        print ('*' * 20)
        print ('Password found: %s' % password)
        print ('Files extracted...')
        exit(0)

# If no password was found by the end, let us know!
print ('Password not found.')
```

I expect the program to find the password which it should be Super + 3 more alphabet characters.

Comment: Check what exception is thrown when you try to open the zip file. E.g. it could be that the file isn't found rather than the password is wrong.

Comment: Also I'd suggest you to create a zip file with the password `Superaaa` to test your code against. That will be the first password your code will try. You can simply add a break at the end of your `for` loop so that you don't have to wait for all the permutations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)` is expecting a password in the form of bytes, not a string. Thus, since a string is passed in as the password, the try/except block within `extractFile` is always triggered, thus the password is never found. I have updated your code to include a byte conversion from a string for the password:

```
import zipfile
import itertools
import time

# Function for extracting zip files to test if the password works!
def extractFile(zip_file, password):
    try:
        zip_file.extractall(pwd=password)
        return True
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
    except Exception:
        pass

# Main code starts here...
# The file name of the zip file.
zipfilename = 'test_archive.zip'
# The first part of the password. We know this for sure!
first_half_password = 'Super'
# We don't know what characters they add afterwards...
# This is case sensitive!
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfilename)

# We know they always have 3 characters after Super...
# For every possible combination of 3 letters from alphabet...
for c in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=3):
    # Slowing it down on purpose to make it work better with the web terminal
    # Remove at your peril
    time.sleep(0.009)
    # Add the three letters to the first half of the password.
    password = first_half_password+''.join(c)
    # Try to extract the file.
    print ("Trying: %s" % password)
    # If the file was extracted, you found the right password.
    if extractFile(zip_file, str.encode(password)):
        print ('*' * 20)
        print ('Password found: %s' % password)
        print ('Files extracted...')
        exit(0)

# If no password was found by the end, let us know!
print ('Password not found.')
```

This is accomplished with the `str.encode` built in method.